# Is the [web-development] tag useful?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

The topic of web development is *extremely* broad, and since we also have the [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) site, anything related to the general discussion of web development should be asked there instead. It seems that this tag just gets added onto questions which are about websites, when it really has no meaning whatsoever.

How exactly does one ask a programming question that is only tagged [web-development](/questions/tagged/web-development)? I don't believe it's possible. I know it's a very popular tag, but I don't see its usefulness.

Similarly, [web-design](/questions/tagged/web-design) can fall under these same conditions.

Should we get rid of these tags?

Comment: I just saw this tag and thought the same thing. Can someone remove these useless tags?

Comment: The problem with [web-developement] is that it doesn't mean anything - you could slap it on any HTML/CSS/JS question. It's as useless as [app-development] or [programming] would be.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Agreed, [web-development](/questions/tagged/web-development) and [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development) and [web-design](/questions/tagged/web-design) are now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: Ohhhh, a colorful image. :o

Comment: There are 704 `[untagged]` questions due to the tag removal. Let's retag them.

Comment: @nhahtdh I deleted the lowest voted Qs, and most of the closed ones. That's about ~100

Comment: Awesome! I'll get on retagging.

Comment: @juhana start here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Buntagged%5D+views%3A500 and work your way down to taste.

Comment: There goes my bronze [web-development] tag badge, but I never really liked it anyway ;)

Comment: I think we should blacklist these tags... [web-development] has risen from the ashes, *worse than ever*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-development

Comment: Now, it's time to burn the [\[web-developer\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-developer) tag.

Answer (score 14):

> The topic of web development is extremely broad, and since we also have the Webmasters.SE site, anything related to the general discussion of web development should be asked there instead. It seems that this tag just gets added onto questions which are about websites, when it really has no meaning whatsoever.

From the [Pro Webmasters FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq):

> #### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Pro Webmasters - Stack Exchange is for professional and enthusiast webmasters. If your question generally covers the operation of websites which you control, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Pro Webmasters has nothing to do with web development, it's for operators of websites, not developers, good questions on web development should be asked on Stack Overflow or Programmers, [depending on perspective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/162704). Worth noting that general discussion of web development would be off topic for any Stack Exchange site, although I think you didn't really meant general discussion (poor choice of words, perhaps?).

That said the tag is a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and I couldn't find a single question that benefits from it - didn't try very hard though, quickly browsed the first couple of pages of [web-development](/questions/tagged/web-development) questions. The tag has 18,671 questions currently and I don't think we can clean it by hand, so if the tag is indeed deemed worthless, we'll need some help from the team to eradicate it.

Comment: What do you mean by "operators of websites"?

Comment: @Pacerier - e.g. people who make sure apache etc and the machine it runs on and how SEO works

Comment: @Mark, programmers need to touch apache as well.

Answer (score 10):

Ending a tag with `development` is always meta on SO. Why do any of these exist? Why not drop them all (or and least the `-development`)?

- <strike>[web-development](/questions/tagged/web-development) **× 20214**</strike> ****deleted****
- <strike>[game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development) **× 8002**</strike> ****deleted****
- <strike>[mobile-development](/questions/tagged/mobile-development) **× 184**</strike> ****retagged*** [mobile](/questions/tagged/mobile)*****
- <strike>[enterprise-development](/questions/tagged/enterprise-development) **× 156**</strike> ****deleted****
- <strike>[dnn-module-development](/questions/tagged/dnn-module-development) **× 102**</strike> ****retagged*** [dotnetnuke-module](/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke-module)*****
- <strike>[plugin-development](/questions/tagged/plugin-development) **× 86**</strike> ****retagged*** [plugin](/questions/tagged/plugin)*****
- <strike>[desktop-development](/questions/tagged/desktop-development) **× 49**</strike> ****deleted****
- <strike>[device-driver-development](/questions/tagged/device-driver-development) **× 14**</strike> ****retagged*** [device-driver](/questions/tagged/device-driver)*****
- <strike>[sharepoint-development](/questions/tagged/sharepoint-development) **× 13**</strike> ****retagged*** [sharepoint](/questions/tagged/sharepoint)*****
- <strike>[windows-development](/questions/tagged/windows-development) **× 12**</strike> ****deleted****
- <strike>[firmware-development](/questions/tagged/firmware-development) **× 8**</strike> ****retagged*** [firmware](/questions/tagged/firmware)*****
- <strike>[extension-development](/questions/tagged/extension-development) **× 6**</strike> ****deleted****
- <strike>[google-development](/questions/tagged/google-development) **× 5**</strike> ****deleted****
- <strike>[ui-development](/questions/tagged/ui-development) **× 3**</strike> ****deleted****
- <strike>[library-development](/questions/tagged/library-development) **× 3**</strike> ****deleted****

Comment: It might make sense for [tag:sharepoint-development] to just be made a synonym of [tag:sharepoint], which I wouldn't think is a meta tag.

Comment: excellent point, the top two are burninated. Sharepoint needs to be tag-merged, I'll email about that.

Comment: A few of those from the bottom of the list have been eliminated...

Comment: I had the count on [tag:sharepoint-development] wrong. Cut-and-paste error.

Comment: extension-development and windows-development are gone.

Comment: Took care of [tag:sharepoint-development], [tag:desktop-development], [tag:plugin-development], and [tag:enterprise-development].

Comment: These have all been completed.

Answer (score 1):

Well the more specific the better. And Web development means you are concentrating on a very wide area. So ya completely agree with you. These must be dropped..!!!

It just misleading also.

Comment: What exactly are you responding to? This tag hasn't existed for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @YannisRizos's answer in that the tag is a meta tag and questions do not benefit from it however I do not see what can be done as the number is so high so not feasible to manually go through all the answers and what could the developer team do.

We should not just remove this tag as it will almost certainly leave questions with no tags or for those with other tags - misleading unhelpful tags.

The best that could be done is could the developers put something in place to stop any more questions being added.

As @Juhana comments the ones on their own could be manually processed.

Comment: There seems to be about 500 questions tagged only web-development - not impossible to manually retag.