# Game-development tag

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

Why is the `game-development` tag removed from stackoverflow? I know I used to tag questions with this tag, now it's not available. Can someone tell me what happened?

Comment: It was [burninated by Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131138/is-the-web-development-tag-useful/140497#140497) this morning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a [GameDevelopment SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) now. [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development) [was burninated by Jeff this morning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140497/131541)

Questions specific to programming issues  in terms of game development generally don't need the [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development) tag. Other non-programming (read: design or concept) questions should be asked on [GameDev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Disclaimer: I have never been on [GameDev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) so I can't claim what's on or off topic there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was confused because it disappeared over night. Also there are now a lot of `Untagged` questions left.