# Blacklist [web-development], [web-developer] and related tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

Ever since [Jeff burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131138/is-the-web-development-tag-useful/140497#140497) [web-development](/questions/tagged/web-development), [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development) and [web-design](/questions/tagged/web-design), these and other similar tags have been resurrected time and again, and we've had to remove these tags from questions every single time.

Can we blacklist these tags already?

Comment: Yes please. [Latest example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13207779/revisions), which isn't that pretty...

Comment: [and again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208743/render-3d-model-orthographically-in-python)...

Comment: There is the related [web-application] tag, but I'm in favor of keeping it.

Answer (score 1):

AAAARRRGGGHHH

I've just removed [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development) from *18* questions that had managed to accumulate it in the last 40 hours. Can this please be blacklisted now?

[What is a sensible algorithm to generate the letters in Letterpress iOS game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216281/what-is-a-sensible-algorithm-to-generate-the-letters-in-letterpress-ios-game)
[Trying to collect wifi data like Metal Gear Solid Portable Ops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216477/trying-to-collect-wifi-data-like-metal-gear-solid-portable-ops)
[Playing png sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218152/cocos2d-2-0-playing-png-sequence)
[How can I upload my game file to my Github account and allow people to run it on their browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216339/how-can-i-upload-my-game-file-to-my-github-account-and-allow-people-to-run-it-on)
[Where to put collision handling in tile based game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218798/where-to-put-collision-handling-in-tile-based-game)
[Rotate a triangle polygon according to mouse position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219408/rotate-a-triangle-polygon-according-to-mouse-position-java)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223084/rotate-a-triangle-polygon-according-to-mouse-position-in-java
[How to move ball on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222926/how-to-move-ball-on-android-main-loop)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224023/what-is-a-good-c-game-creation-library-to-use-for-a-beginner
[XNA Game Studio 4.0 Platform Scrolling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224451/xna-game-studio-4-0-platform-scrolling-issue)
[Calibrate UIAccelerometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225713/calibrate-uiaccelerometer)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226475/chess-item-icons-under-mit-license
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226787/cumulative-scoring-in-game-center
[Sort a text file where each line is a name followed by a score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232448/im-trying-to-work-out-a-way-to-sort-a-text-file-where-each-line-is-a-name-follo)
[How to drag an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237147/gamesalad-how-to-drag-an-object)
[Min-Max Evaluation function for a game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237837/min-max-evaluation-function-for-a-game)
[Optimising particle effects for slower phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229482/optimising-particle-effe)
[Implementing gravity to projectile - delta time issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241700/implementing-gravity-to-projectile-delta-time-issuects-for-slower-phones)

This is highly appropriate at the moment:

[image: I'm off to bed now]

Comment: Wow, [tag:game-development] is back with a vengeance.  It looks like *something* reversed the synonym of it and [tag:game].  [Maybe this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157453/135887)?

Comment: I'd bet on you being right @Charles; especially since the [game-development] wiki page is now kaput: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/game-development/info