# Burninate the [game-development] tag (again)

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

In response to Animuson's blacklist request, [Jeff burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131138/is-the-web-development-tag-useful/140497#140497) [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development), [web-development](/questions/tagged/web-development) and [web-design](/questions/tagged/web-design) on the 20<sup>th</sup> July 2012 and back in September [BoltClock asked for a blacklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148168/179419) of these three.

I've just gone to see if there was anything new that needed cleaning up in [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development) and found a slightly scary 143 questions:

> [image]

Not quick to do but easy enough. Clicking on it though yielded a scarier [569 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-development) as [game-design](/questions/tagged/game-design), [game](/questions/tagged/game), [games](/questions/tagged/games), [highscores](/questions/tagged/highscores), and [highscore](/questions/tagged/highscore) have all been made [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/game-development/synonyms).

Is game development [burninated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm85C.png)?

If it's not can it be burninated again, along with its synonyms, and BoltClock's blacklist request implemented?

Comment: Burninate them all, for great justice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development) burninated again. Would've helped if all those synonyms (and merges) hadn't been done.

Comment: `game` (previous synonym) is already back.  Three questions in the past 12 hours.  Sigh...

Comment: These tags are a never-ending and ever-returning cesspit @Charles. I would _really_ like for every tag mentioned in my question to be blacklisted. Not much hope of a proper tag bonfire though :-(.

Answer (score 3):

[web-development](/questions/tagged/web-development) and [web-design](/questions/tagged/web-design) are gone now. However of [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development) somebody must still take care of, the use is growing.