# What is the gaming tag for?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags, burninate-request

The [gaming](/questions/tagged/gaming) tag has 128 questions. The excerpt makes it seem as an overly general tag.

> Questions directly related to computer gaming and interactive
>   graphics/video

What is it for?

Should we burninate it?

Answer (score 4):

Well, almost all questions in that tag is based on Game development. I remember we had a `Game-Development` tag once, but it was [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131138/is-the-web-development-tag-useful/140497#140497). So `gaming` should be too.

Game development is a broad topic and a tag for the whole topic doesn't serve any purpose. And for overly broad/non specific (non SO) questions there is [gamedev stackexchange site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) too..

Comment: It *could* be used for 'Gamification' which might get On-Topic questions. There are [a few example questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gamification) on this already, but probably not enough to be tag-worthy yet.

Comment: @JonW, 34 questions is enough for a tag.  Hell, two is enough for a tag if the topic is interesting enough.  Getting gamification split from "gaming" will be a great thing if we're really (finally!) stamping out the gaming tags.